# How to display the contents of an object array in thymeleaf Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is the HTML code with thymeleaf:

```
<thead>
  <div>
    <label>Nom lecteur :</label>
    <label th:text="${param.motCle}"></label>
 </div>
    <tr>
     <th>NomLecteur</th><th>DESIGNATION</th><th>AUTEUR</th><th>Date_Edition</th>
    </tr>                   
</thead>
```

and here's the Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="listPret")
 public String indexPret(Model model,
  @RequestParam(name="page",defaultValue="0")int p,
  @RequestParam(name="size",defaultValue="7")int s,          
  @RequestParam(name="motCle",defaultValue="")String mc,             
  @RequestParam(name="pret.lecteur.nom",defaultValue="0")
                               String nom)  {
        Page<Pret> 
 pagePrets=pretRepository.chercher("%"+mc+"%",new PageRequest(p, s));
        model.addAttribute("listPrets",pagePrets.getContent());
        int[] pages=new int[pagePrets.getTotalPages()];
        model.addAttribute("pages",pages);
        model.addAttribute("size", s);
        model.addAttribute("pageCourante",p);
        model.addAttribute("motCle",mc);
        model.addAttribute("pret.lecteur.nom",nom);
            return "listPret";  
}
```

And here is the result on the interface. the content is not displaying but this one :

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@7598d00e
```

here is the interface:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMVj0.png)
Thank you ! For your help!

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you print an array reference directly.

The output of

```
String[] helloWorld = {"Hello", "World"};
System.out.println(helloWorld);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(helloWorld));
```

is

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@45a877
[Hello, World]
```

(the number after `@` is almost always different)

SO the answer to your question is set the array inside model attribute by above approach.

Comment: excuse me for can not answer that now. In fact I want to retrieve the content of the attribution to display (here we want to display the name of the author). Thank you!

Comment: le code <label th: text = "$ {motCle}">> [Valeur de motcle] </ label> affiche le fragment de mot du mot que je tape dans le formulaire de recherche. Mais ce que je veux afficher, c’est le contenu exact du "nomLecteur". Merci pour le dérangement! @Extraterrestre

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You do not need the `param` syntax in this case.  You can simply print:

`<label th:text="${motCle}">[Value of motcle]</label>`

This will call `toString()` on the `motCle` `String` that is already included in your Controller method.

The param syntax is necessary if you're looking to directly extract a query parameter, as referenced in the [Thymeleaf docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html).

Note that you can also shorten the mapping to `@GetMapping("listPret")` in this case.

Also, be sure to include some text between your HTML tags.  When you open the HTML without a container (Tomcat), the browser will still display the page with static elements and give you an idea of what the design will look like.

EDIT: if you are looking to print the value of `nom`, then change the string value parameter to something like the following to see what you are actually doing:

```
@GetMapping("listPret")
public String indexPret(@RequestParam(name="page",
                                      defaultValue="0") int p,
                        @RequestParam(name="size",
                                      defaultValue="7") int s,          
                        @RequestParam(name="motCle",
                                      defaultValue="") String mc,             
                        @RequestParam(name="nom",
                                      defaultValue="0") String nom, 
                        Model model)  {

       //...other code here
       System.out.println("nom="+nom); //temporarily print this value to see what you will be displaying
       model.addAttribute("nomLecture", nom); //note that the variable you have here is always what you would put in the HTML
            return "listPret";  
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<label th:text="${nomLecture}">[Value of nomLecture]</label>
```

The "dot" operator in Java means that you are accessing a property of an object, so be careful when you use it.

Comment: excuse me for can not answer that now. In fact I want to retrieve the content of the attribution to display (here we want to display the name of the author). Thank you!

Comment: the code <label th: text = "$ {motCle}"> [Value of motcle] </ label> displays the word fragment of the word that I type in the search form. But what I want to display is the exact content of the "nomLecteur".
Thanks for the inconvenience! @bphilipnyc

Comment: Ok, it seems you will want to take a look at your parameter.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your availability ! but it displays "0" for each search @bphilipnyc

Comment: it displays "name = 0" @bphilipnyc

Comment: Ok, so you may be not providing a value to `http://localhost:8080/listpret` - check how you are creating it.  Try adding some parameters like `http://localhost:8080/listpret?nom=1` to see whether it would print.

Comment: Excuse me, the delay of my answer, the result of http: // localhost: 8082 / listPret? name = 1 is equal "name = 1", Thank's! @bphilipnyc

Comment: ok, so then look at how you are calling the page.  It's printing whatever you give it.  Please read the Thymeleaf and Spring documentation from here if you are unclear.